# Clustered Index Cost is high using Sql Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-performance

I have given a task to optimize the below sql query. It is currently performing badly. I ran the execution plan for it, and i see it is doing Clustered Index Scan, and it's cost is very high. How can i reduce the cost or it is possible to change it to use Index seek instead?

```
SELECT TOP 20 CustomerPrimaryExtID,
              Max(POSTimeStamp)     AS TransactionDate,
              ExtLocationCode,
              0                     AS RedemptionAmount,
              0                     AS RedemptionCount,
              TerminalNum,
              LogixTransNum,
              POSTransNum           AS TransNum,
              0                     AS DetailRecords,
              CustomerTypeID,
              PresentedCustomerID,
              PresentedCardTypeID,
              HHID,
              Replayed,
              0                     AS TransContext,
              isnull(TransTotal, 0) AS TransTotal

FROM   TransHist AS TH WITH(nolock)
WHERE  ( ( ( CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' )
             AND HHID IS NULL )            

            OR HHID = '0000000250000013408'
               AND CustomerTypeID <> 1 )                            

          OR ( CustomerPrimaryExtID = '0000000250000013408'
               AND CustomerTypeID = 1 ) )           

       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT LogixTransNum
                       FROM   TransRedemption AS TR2 with(nolock)
                       WHERE  ( ( ( CustomerPrimaryExtID IN ( '' )
                                    AND HHID IS NULL )
                                   OR HHID = '0000000250000013408'
                                      AND CustomerTypeID <> 1 )
                                 OR ( CustomerPrimaryExtID = '0000000250000013408'
                                      AND CustomerTypeID = 1 ) )
                              AND TH.LogixTransNum = TR2.LogixTransNum)

GROUP  BY CustomerPrimaryExtID,
          HHID,
          CustomerTypeID,
          PresentedCustomerID,
          PresentedCardTypeID,
          LogixTransNum,
          POSTransNum,
          TerminalNum,
          ExtLocationCode,
          Replayed,
          TransTotal
ORDER  BY TransactionDate DESC
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: without putting any real effort into looking at your query... whenever I see a slow query using an `OR`, I try using a `UNION`.  you need to determine what indexes are you trying to use and figure out why they are not being used (or create them if necessary)

Comment: What is the fragmentation level on your slow index?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note: `CustomerTypeID <> 1` will not use indexes as effectively as CustomerTypeID > 1, see the below test example.  Also, `WHERE NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN` are also performance killers.

```
CREATE TABLE NumberCrazy(
    IntegersAreCool INT
)

-- Run this 20+ times
INSERT INTO NumberCrazy
VALUES (1)

-- Run this twice
DECLARE @begin INT = 1, @max INT = 2000, @r INT

WHILE @begin <= @max
BEGIN

    SET @r = (RAND()*(@begin))

    INSERT INTO NumberCrazy
    SELECT @r

    SET @begin = @begin + 1

END

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DaInts] ON [dbo].[NumberCrazy]
(
    [IntegersAreCool] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

GO

SET STATISTICS IO ON

SELECT *
FROM NumberCrazy
WHERE IntegersAreCool > 1

SELECT *
FROM NumberCrazy
WHERE IntegersAreCool <> 1
```

Results:

Table 'NumberCrazy'. Scan count 1, logical reads 12, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

Table 'NumberCrazy'. Scan count 2, logical reads 15, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

`NOTE THE EXECUTION PLAN` (Looks like the mess you have above this).